# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/\sqrt[n]{n}$ converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Does the series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}
$$
converge or diverge?

I'm unsure where to start with this question. I know that $n$<sup>th</sup> root of $n$ converges to $1$ but not sure about its reciprocal.

Comment: If $a_n \to 1$ then $1/a_n \to 1/1 = 1$...

Comment: The reciprocal also converges to $1$, hence the series cannot converge since the limit would have to be $0$.

Comment: You can approach this intuitively. Plug a large number in, like $500$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[500]{500}} \approx 0.9876
$$
Now you could guess that it's essentially $1$'s that you're adding together. $1+1+1+1 + \ldots $... So what do you conclude?

Comment: Your sum diverges. Ideed, notice that for $n\ge 1$ we have $\frac{1}{n^{\frac{1}{n}}} \ge \frac{1}{n}$ Hence you sum is $\ge$ the harmonic sum which is known to diverge.

Comment: If you know that a sequence converges to $L$, then you also know what the reciprocal converges to !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, prove by induction that
$2^n > n$.

Therefore
$n^{1/n} < 2$
so
$1/n^{1/n} > 1/2$
and the sum of these diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\to 1$$

indeed

$$\sqrt[n]{n}=e^{\frac{\log n}n}\to e^0=1$$

therefore the series diverges.

As an alternative

$$n^n\ge n \implies n\ge n^\frac1n \implies  \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\ge \frac1n$$

Answer (score 0):

The series diverges. We know that $n^{1/n}\approx1 $ for arbitrarily large values of $n$, so $\frac{1}{n^{1/n}}\approx1/1=1$.

Thus, as 100% of numbers are arbitrarily close to 1, we are essentially adding $1$ repeatedly, so the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

If a series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges, then $\lim_na_n=0$. Therefore your series diverges.